# How to get the filename and line number of a Django template error when calling render()?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I'm using the Django template system in a standalone tool (not in a web app), like so:

```
from django import template

try:
    tmpl = loader.get_template(my_template_path)
    context = template.Context(my_template_context)
    txt = tmpl.render(context)
except (template.TemplateSyntaxError, template.TemplateDoesNotExist), e:
    # ...
```

When a template contains an error, an exception is thrown.  How do I get the filename, line number, and line position of the error?  Should I expect to get this information from the exception in this case (not rendering a response for a browser)?

I notice that `TemplateSyntaxError` has a `source` attribute whose value is a tuple containing a `LoaderOrigin` and a pair of numbers.  The `LoaderOrigin` has a `name` equal to the filename.  The numbers do not appear to resemble the character positions of the error, but maybe there's another way to interpret them?

`TemplateDoesNotExist` does not appear to have a `source`, only `args` and `message`, which provide the name of the template that could not be found.  Is there a way to locate the template tag doing the loading, or does this error happen at a later phase when line numbers are no longer available?

I do have `django.settings` in effect, and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is set to `True`, if that matters.  (I believe this is needed to get line numbers reported when rendering templates into webpages, with the fancy error display.)  I am also using a trivial template loader, set via `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`, though I don't think that should matter.  Also, I'm stuck with Django 1.3 at the moment, so a 1.3-compatible solution would be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I can help you, but if all else fails, you might check the django-debug-toolbar source code for how it handles errors, or dig into the templating code itself. Every time I've had to dig into the Django code, I've found it to be pretty easily comprehenisbile.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled This is one type of template support provided by django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `source` attribute of the `TemplateSyntaxError` is what you are looking for. Django code implies that the mentioned numbers are line numbers between which an error occured, see https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.7/django/views/debug.py#L153.

As for `TemplateDoesNotExist`, it seems to be ignored, when it occurs as a result of the template tag, see https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.7/django/template/loader.py#L50.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like my main problem is `TemplateSyntaxError` is not getting a `source` attr within my actual app, even though `settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is `True` just before I call my loader. One lousy workaround would be to invoke `DebugLexer` and `DebugParser` directly, then render the nodelist, instead of using the `Template` class. I'll see if I can do better.

Comment: After more poking around: It is using `DebugParser`, but in my test case, `TemplateSyntaxError` is raised by `FilterExpression.__init__()` and at no point is it caught in order to annotate it with a `source`.  I expected the parser's `compile_function_error()` to be called during `parse()`, but this doesn't happen if the error is in a filter expression.  (There _is_ a `token` available, but it isn't used in this case.) So the best case is to test for `hasattr(e, 'source')` and use it only if found.

Comment: @Dan: I expected the `compile_function_error()` would be called as well. Sorry for that.